# How to set back the USB device to its factory state?

Tags: usb, formatting

I've a `2GB Kingston USB` drive. I'm using it on USB audio device and two days ago its started to hanging at some tracks. So I format the device and copy-paste the tracks again but the result was same.
Now I deleted the partition and recreated it, but now the USB audio device doesn't read it and other USB devices working fine on the USB audio device.
So my question is what should I do to reset the USB device to its factory setting.

Comment: Try formatting it as FAT32 or maybe even FAT16. It could help.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the USB drive isn't the drive like a spinning platter drive. It is essentially a flash memory chip with a USB interface. The best of the drives (SLC) Single Level Cell NAND flash would last about 100,000 writes but are way more expensive than the standard fare you can pick on your way out of the superstore along some mint or cigarette.

Those are (MLC) Multi-Level Cell which support only about 10000 writes. The USB connector too cant last too long either. Approx 1000-1500 plug-ins.

The NAND flash operations are irreversible and its better to think of the drives as erstwhile floppies and not rely too much on them or get too attached either.